# How to get a user from their ID

Tags: java, discord

I have a shop in my discord bot that allows you to buy items with coins, this item causes the bot to message me, but it errors everytime it attempts to send a message to me, and another problem is if a different guild has my bot it won't be able to find me, I need an alternative.

Most Ideal Method: Getting a user using their ID without the requirement of a guild.

```
guild.getMemberById("348136128932610058").getUser().openPrivateChannel().queue(schannel -> schannel.sendMessage(user.getName() + " just bought a strange fragment (feature)").queue());
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at checken.chen.App.onMessageReceived(App.java:152)
at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:428)
at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:82)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:69)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:152)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:122)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:954)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:841)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:819)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:992)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [openPrivateChannelById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#openPrivateChannelById(java.lang.String)):

```java
guild.getJDA().openPrivateChannelById("348136128932610058")
  .flatMap(schannel -> schannel.sendMessage(user.getName() + " just bought a strange fragment (feature)"))
  .queue();
```

The channel includes the user with [PrivateChannel#getUser](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/PrivateChannel.html#getUser()).

Alternatively, you can lookup the user with [retrieveUserById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#retrieveUserById(java.lang.String)) in the same way.